# Why don't the returning beams split a second time when they hit the half reflecting mirror in Michelson-Morley Experiment?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, visible-light, applied-physics, aether

I understand the role of interference pattern in Michelson Morley experiment.I have just watched three videos, they all pretty much explain the set up in the same fashion. But none actually mentions the issue about the returning beams. See,the job of the partially reflective mirror at the center is to let half the light pass and reflect the other half. Fine,I see it happening in the first stage, when a beam arrives from the source. After splitting,each beam bounces back after hitting two separate mirrors perpendicularly and returns to the half-reflecting mirror at the center. Now,this time, they don't split as the first beam, despite the center mirror still being a partially reflective mirror. Could anyone please explain if I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The second pass does split the return beam again. It is probably ignored because only one branch is interesting.